# Is there a cellular mechanism that detects Ribosomal damage?

Tags: proteins, rna, amino-acids, ribosome

What kinds of options, if any, do cells (Eukary and Prokary) have for detecting, and repairing damage in Ribosomes (of all types)? I am curious as to 
what happens when a cell sustains damage of some form, such as radiation, and the Ribosomes are damaged.

Comment: I think you should check rRNA synthesis regulation: http://www.nature.com/cdd/journal/v20/n11/images/cdd2013107f1.jpg . So it seems to be regulated by sensing stress and not the ribosome damage directly. Another possible mechanism to measure the mRNA synthesis rate and if it is too high, then build a new ribosome. Maybe there is something like that too in the background, I don't know, interesting question.

Comment: I'm unaware of any repair mechanisms. Damaged proteins and RNA are usually dealt with by degradation.